# Get facebook app install timestamp

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

How can I get using the JS api only the install time of the currently used facebook application?

In general I would like to verify that the user that currently online is a new user and not already registered returning user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FB.getLoginStatus`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) as recomended [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/05/08/how-to--improve-the-experience-for-returning-users/) it can tell you weather visitor are logged into facebook and if so if they are registered with your application.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

Comment: I already know he logged in to facebook and to my application. I am looking for a generic way to know if this is his first login to the application. So for this purpose I need app installation time stamp or some flag in fb API that indicates first login.

Other solutions are welcome. 

Thanks, Oren.

Comment: Any user that returns 'not_authorized' is necessarily new to your application. You should mark him as new (use a cookie). As soon as you have a user log in check if the "new user"  cookie is set, if so you know this is his first login.

Comment: On second thought, this method may not allow you to identify a new user that is not logged into facebook and logs in through your site.

Comment: I am making a plugin to facebook application. So I need a generic way using JS to identify logged in user just registered or not. I can't use your solution because I don't know all of the users from day one.